# IntelliSense: the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a class called Person:

```
class Person {
    string name;
    long score;
public:
    Person(string name="", long score=0);
    void setName(string name);
    void setScore(long score);
    string getName();
    long getScore();
};
```

In another class, I have this method:

```
void print() const {
     for (int i=0; i< nPlayers; i++)
        cout << "#" << i << ": " << people[i].getScore()//people is an array of person objects
    << " " << people[i].getName() << endl;
}
```

This is the declaration of people:

```
    static const int size=8; 
    Person people[size];
```

When I try to compile it I get this error:

```
IntelliSense: the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function
```

with red lines under the the 2 **people[i]** in the print method

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the definition of `people`?  Does it have any `const` qualifiers in it anywhere?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`getName` is not const, `getScore` is not const, but `print` is. Make the first two const like `print`. You cannot call a non-const method with a const object. Since your Person objects are direct members of your other class and since you are in a const method they are considered const.

In general you should consider every method you write and declare it const if that's what it is. Simple getters like `getScore` and `getName` should always be const.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about this: "Since your Person objects are direct members of your other class and since you are in a const method they are considered const" Thanks!

Comment: In your other class you have (I presume) `Person people[size];`. This means that within a `const` method of your other class you are not allowed to change the `people` array, so for instance `people[0] = x;` would be illegal. Calling a non-const `Person` method is just another way of changing the `people` array, so `people[0].setScore(20.0);` would also be illegal. Because you didn't declare `Person::getScore()` as const the compiler didn't know that you weren't trying to change the `people` array, so it gave an error.