# problem of using const when passing a pointer

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

Visual studio shows a error saying "*the object has type quantifiers that are not compatible with the member function 'somfunc'* "

```
class T_ship {
    public:    
        ... 
        float ship_run(int ship_len);
        // function ship_run doesn't change any class member values
};
```

There is a function in `main()`  with `*T_ship` pointer passed as input.

```
void draw_ship(const T_ship * a_shp){

    float dist = a_ship-> ship_run(100); 
    // there is a red wavy line under a_ship     
}
```

Many thanks if someone can help.

Comment: Please add the main function.

Comment: Why isn't `ship_run` a `const` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the actual pointer to be const and not the object pointed to, put the `const` in front of the type, so like this:

`T_ship * const`

**However** in your case if the function `ship_run` doesn't modify anything you should
mark it as `const` at the end of the function as well so like this:

`float ship_run(int v) const { /* your code here */ }`

Comment: The question is repeated, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103755/intellisense-the-object-has-type-qualifiers-that-are-not-compatible-with-the-me/13103791, "You cannot call a non-const method with a const object. " It is resovled by `float ship_run(int v) const { /* your code here */ }`. Thank you.